# URL to check if IP is in the EU

Tags: json, ip, amp-html

Does anyone know if there's a service to check if an IP address is in the EU? I'm trying to implement a cookie notification on my website but I only want to show it if it's required by law.

I'm trying to implement this using AMP, and it gives the option to use a URL to check if the notification should be displayed. I know this is probably a long shot, but it needs to return a result like this: (based on the URL the request came from).

```
{
   "showNotification":true
}
```

I'll probably just end up creating something, just wanted to check on the off chance that someone already did

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out how to do this with [amp-geo](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-user-notification?referrer=ampproject.org#data-show-if-geo) - I thought I'd share the answer in case anyone else came across it:

Include these JS files:

```
<script async custom-element="amp-user-notification" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-user-notification-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-geo" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-geo-0.1.js"></script>
```

Include this code:

```
<amp-geo layout="nodisplay">
  <script type="application/json">
  {
    "ISOCountryGroups": {
      "ineu": ["al","ad","at","az","by","be","ba","bg","hr","cy","cz","dk","ee","fi","fr","ge","de","gr","hu","is","ie", "it","kz","xk","lv","li","lt","lu","mk","mt","md","mc","me","nl","no","pl","pt","ro","ru","sm","rs","sk", "si","es","se","ch","tr","ua","gb","va"]
    }
  }
  </script>
</amp-geo>

<amp-user-notification id="cookie-notif" layout="nodisplay" data-show-if-geo="ineu">
    <div>
        This site uses third-party cookies, <a href="/privacy/">learn more</a> or <a on="tap:cookie-notif.dismiss" class="ampstart-btn caps ml1">accept</a>
    </div>
</amp-user-notification>
```